# SIM900A GSM module related AT command to know the number of message sender

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, at-command

I am using SIM900A for some purpose and want to know the number of the sender from where message come.I am unable to find the a specific AT command related to receiving message which give me number from where latest message comes.

I had used AT+CNMI (it corresponds to notification regarding latest received message ) but unable to find sender number.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the message in PDU mode, the modem should provide you with absolutely all information the message contains, and I am quite sure that includes the sender's phone number. The "only" problem then left is to decipher the response to extract only the sender's phone number.